# Git commit fatal error

Tags: git

when I enter in console:

```
git init
git add .
```

all OK

when I enter:

```
git commit -m "final"
```

I get:

```
error: object file .git/objects/18/d50376886bb9702194048cd450960abe40d223 is empty
error: unable to find 18d50376886bb9702194048cd450960abe40d223
fatal: 18d50376886bb9702194048cd450960abe40d223 is not a valid object
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Probably, there is no file named `d50376886bb9702194048cd450960abe40d223` in the directory `18`. May be, it happened because after executing `git add .`, this file was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `git add .`, whatever new and changed files you had in the current directory gets staged into git's version control. This is where the contents of the files gets stored as git objects available under `.git/objects`.

In your case, a new git object with the hash `18d50376886bb9702194048cd450960abe40d223` is created for this content which is stored as `.git/objects/18/d50376886bb9702194048cd450960abe40d223`

The problem looks like, after you ran the `git add` command, this file either did not get written to the hard drive correctly, or could have been deleted later or even corrupted due to some hard disk errors.

Comment: What should be the solution to the problem? re-install git or delinting all .git files?

Comment: @technobot: first of all, make a backup of the repo (throw the whole repo folder into a tar or something); if you want, you can try to salvage by using [`git fsck`](http://goo.gl/BUB8u) (http://sethrobertson.github.com/GitFixUm/ might help too); otherwise, or if that doesn't work, re-clone the repo if possible (assuming you have previously pushed that repo to a remote)