# Missing dependency for git commit?

Tags: linux, git, dependencies

I was unable to git commit on an old Synology DS-106j for a while. After asking this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932599/what-is-wrong-with-my-git-1-8-4-2-1) a while back, I followed the suggested alternative till I found out that I now need to use git on the platform. (I am currently writing a program for it.) Fortunately, I found a way to get an updated version of git for the platform, but the issue is still there even after the update. Below is a short version of what happened:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Testing"
fatal: d7fae4dbad5534fed92205ff4a9cc1152b013c8b is not a valid object
```

I tried again by deleting the .git directory; yet, the similar result shows. In the previous question, it is possible that it may be a version problem since I was running git version 1.8.4.2-1, but the problem still persist after updated to version 2.3.7.

The strange part is that I tested git version 2.3.5 on a newer Synology DS-212j and it works perfectly fine. Maybe that my old platform is missing a dependency or something of that sort?

Comment: This looks like a nasty problem, but have you a had a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613682/how-do-you-restore-a-corrupted-object-in-a-git-repository-for-newbies) SO post?

Comment: Oh, no need for that since I am not trying to recover the repo. I am just trying to commit, which I can't even do that.

Comment: I think you may need to recover the repo _before_ you can commit.

Comment: But it is before my first commit though, I just create the repo and perform the commit after staging. You are saying that the initial repo creation is corrupted to begin with?